# how to slice dates of data queried through database?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, influxdb-python

How can I slice the data using std input function ?

My data is as follows:

```
                 time                duration
0 2018-07-04 12:19:29+00:00         4000000000
1 2018-07-04 12:20:30+00:00         4000000000
2 2018-07-04 12:21:31+00:00         3700000000
3 2018-07-04 12:22:31+00:00         4100000000
4 2018-07-04 12:23:31+00:00         4100000000
```

I queried data from influxdb and then converted to a Dataframe.
It gives me a error `SyntaxError: invalid token` when giving input to `Starting date :`

I tried to split the `time` column as separate `date` and `Time`

```
import influxdb
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

client = influxdb.DataFrameClient('192.168.1.108' , port = 8086, database = 'Mlogi_01081081')

dfs_dict = client.query('select * from sy_1')

measurement = next(iter(dfs_dict))

ret = dfs_dict[measurement]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ret)

df = df.reset_index()

df.rename( columns={'index':'time'}, inplace=True )

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time

df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index(['date'])

a = input('Starting_Date: ')
b = input('Ending_Date :')

starting_date = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
ending_date = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

df.loc[starting_date:ending_date]
```

Still no luck !!!

Comment: Using between .

Comment: Are you trying to filter the dataframe with the `time` column?

Comment: So this is what you wanted to do `df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time

df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date` ? Is this not working in your case?

Comment: I have split the `time` column to separate `date` and `time` column so that I can slice the dataframe as `Starting date` and `Ending date` using `date ` column by `std input ` means...

Hope I cleared the thing I need @user2906838

Comment: is your std_input working? So your date field is `datetime.date` right?

Comment: No std_input is only giving the error ...I have updated the question, kindly have a look.

Comment: Ok, let me reproduce it and update my answer.

Comment: are you using python2.7?

Comment: yes. python 2.7 @user2906838

Comment: Please check my answer now, you need to quote your input in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your go, from your question, I'm assuming that you want to get all the data between two times using `date` as your designated column to do the filter. As requested by the OP, since he is using Python 2.7, the typed input should be quoted " " like this for user's input to work.

```
>>> input("please type the date: ") 
please type the date: 2016-08-09
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    2016-08-09
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> input("please type the date: ") 
please type the date: "2018-07-09" 
'2018-07-09'
```

Now to the real problem of filtering the data, here's what you can do:

```
newdf = df[(df["date"]>starting_date) and df["date"]<=ending_date]
```

This should give you your expected result. But you have to make sure that `df["date"]` has the same datatype as of `starting_date` and `ending_date`.

Comment: I want dates to be chosen as std input from console @user2906838

Comment: Yes, for that I assume your `input` code is just fine, what's wrong there?

Comment: I have updated the question kindly have a look on split `time` approach @user2906838

Comment: I'm very unclear at this moment, about what exactly are you trying to achieve, and what is not working.

Comment: `newdf = df[(df["date"]>Starting_date) and df["date"]<=Ending_date] ]`  gives invalid syntax in the spyder IDLE  :(

Comment: please check, you're assigning `staring_date` as your date variable and using `Starting_date`. You should watch that out yourself.

Comment: Thanks @user2906838

Comment: Coo, please accept and upvote if it helped you. thanks

Comment: remove the last `]` from `newdf = df[(df["date"]>Starting_date) and df["date"]<=Ending_date]  ]` and update your answer. Thank you :)